# Is there a way to copy a matrix but with different indices?

Tags: java, list, matrix, indexing

I'm a beginner developer and i have a problem with the copy of a matrix.

I have two lists with the following values:

```
LinkedList<Integer> Origin = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            Origin.add(0,1);
            Origin.add(1,2);
            Origin.add(2,3);
LinkedList<Integer> Dest = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            Dest.add(0,2);
            Dest.add(1,3);
            Dest.add(2,1);
```

and i have this double c [][]

```
[[0.5, 0.4791428571428572, 0.0], [0.0, Infinity, Infinity], [0.4791428571428572, 0.0, Infinity]]
```

I created this double with normal indices i and j from 0 to 3.

Now i would create a matrix with the values of c, but with the index of the lists (i for origin and j for Dest).

I i write this

```
int N=3;
 double[][]e=new double[N][N];
     for (int i = 0; i <N; i++){
           e[Origin.get(i)-1]=new double[N];
           for (int j = 0; j <N; j++){
               e[Origin.get(i)-1][Dest.get(j)-1]=c[i][j];      
           System.out.println(e[i][j]);
```

i obtain this:

```
0.0
0.5
0.4791428571428572
0.0
0.0
Infinity
0.0
0.4791428571428572
0.0
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: I ran the same code but with 1000 instead of infinity, and here's what I got:
```
0.0           0.5                               0.4791428571428 
infinity     0.0                              infinity 
infinity     0.4791428571428      0.0 ```
was this the supposed result? I edited a couple of times but the markdown doesn't seem to work but here;s the code I used to print:
```
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   for(int j =0; j < N; j++){
    System.out.print(e[i][j] + " ");
   }
   p.println();
  }
```

Comment: The values in e are automatically initilized to 0.0, so if you want to see the value you just copied you should do System.out.print(e[Origin.get(i)-1][Dest.get(j)-1])